# How to determine the IP address and SSH into a hostapd server?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh

I've started the [hostapd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostapd) deamon and am able to connect to it via Wi-Fi. Now I want to SSH from the connected device into the server that started the hostapd WiFi. The SSH deamon is running of course.

The problem is that I don't know the IP address. How can I figure this out? or configure it properly?

It seems that the server does not have an IP address for `wlan0` when in AP mode.

And the connected device seems to be connected to a network with 65536 possible IP addresses. Can I limit this to 256 IP addresses?

Is this even something to be configured via hostapd? Or do I need to configure another service for that?

Note that I do not share an internet connection for the connected devices. I just want them to be able to SSH into the server via its own Wi-Fi.

Comment: Im not sure you can determine the IP address using the information you have provided - AFAIK hostapd works below the IP level.  If you know the make of computer, maybe you can do a portscan and use mac address lookups to narrow down the list of pissible IP's?

Comment: FWIW, "And the connected device seems to be connected to a network with 65536 possible IP addresses.": if the network is 169.254.0.0/16 that means the device attempted DHCP and it failed, so it chose an IPv4LL address as fallback.

Comment: The missing DHCP server was the important hint. Now it works, I can connect via SSH. To put sugar on top, can I make the server available for its hostname.local? Or do I need a DNS server for that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign wlan0 an ip address first. Then bring it up. Like.
`sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.5/24 dev wlan0` or whatever your ip is, then `sudo ip link set dev wlan0 up`. Then if you have hostapd running and conf right you should be able to ssh.

Comment: Tried that. But I still cannot connect to 10.0.0.5 via SSH.